# php-apache curl returns (7) Failed to connect to 10.96.128.220 port 80: No route to host

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, php, curl, kubernetes

I have 3 kube services (PHP-apache) that I am trying to curl but it always returns the same error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.96.128.220 port 80: No route to host
```

Does anyone have any idea of why this happens?
I tried disabling my Firewall but it didn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was that we needed to reapply weave net!